# styling autocompletion boxes for form fields

Tags: css

Is it possible to style autocompletion boxes that appear under text inputs? I'd like to change background color and border.

[image]

Comment: @TimSPQR: this is standard browser feature: http://jsfiddle.net/Sjx6a/1/

Comment: First write something into the field and then press enter. Then RUN again and start typing the same thing. If your browser is Firefox or Chrome, you should see the box. Not sure about other browsers.

Comment: TimSPQR: did the grey box has appeared? It shows the entries you input into the field before.

Comment: I apologize for answering. This is far above me - I'm pretty good at jQuery autocomplete and have learned of its quirks, but this built-in one is not something I have expertise in. I'll delete my comments above, wait a few minutes, then delete this one. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this by using javascript.

Another way to do this is by opening up your developer tools.. "View - Developer - Developer Tools" using the magnifying glass to hover your element, get the class or ID name and make direct edits in the right hand side, then paste that code within your stylesheet. ( sounds harder than it is! )